# External CSS referenced into HTML

Tags: css

In a homework assignment, I am asked to create the following:
In cyclestyles04.css, add the styles to constrain the wrapper to 80% of the width of the window and to center the content within the wrapper. Save all files and then open or refresh the pages in a browser to make sure that the content is centered within 80% of the browser window. (Hint: Note that a nav section to link to each of the four pages follows the image on each page.)

7. On the cyclehome04.html and cyclefaq04.html pages, you want to oat the image in the header to the right. On the cycleevents04.html and cycleabout04.html pages, you want to  oat the image in the header to the left. Complete these tasks as follows:

   a. Create styles in your style sheet with a selector that addresses the class names of  floatleft and  floatright. (Hint: A class="floatleft" attribute and value in the HTML document is referenced by a .floatleft selector in the CSS ¬file.)

   b. Add two declarations to both the selectors. The fi¬rst will  oat the content either left or right. The second will add a 2% margin to the inside edge of the content. For example, the declarations for the . floatleft selector would be:
   .floatleft {float: left;
   margin-right: 2%;

So I'm aware I need to use <nav but I am unsure about the full format for I already created #wrapper and some other CSS code that gets it done. I am following my textbook, but the textbook as both and I'm unsure how to write the code.

I haven't tried anything because I'm confused as to how it's supposed to be laid out. Right now I have:

`#wrapper { width: 80%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`

which works but then isn't what my instructions tell me to do afterwards.